# bootstrap 3 modal ID and classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So I am trying to create simple modal views using the bootstrap.min css framework and am having trouble creating multiple different modals. I know it has something to do with the ID's and classes (I am aware ID's are unique and classes can be used repeatedly)...so I assume it has something to do with re-naming/editing id=myModalLabel...? Below is my code thus far, which works to for portfolioModal1 but not with portfolioModal2. The button for portfolioModal2 launches but then the modal view is blank...

Thank you very much for the help!

html:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="team-member">
                        <img src="img/portfolio/dan-circle.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                        <h4>Dan Druffel</h4>
                        <center><p class="text-muted">CEO</p></center>
                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul><br>
<a href="#portfolioModal1" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#portfolioModal1">About Dan</a>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="team-member">
                        <img src="img/portfolio/pody-circle.png" class="img-responsive img-circle" alt="">
                        <h4>Pody Druffel</h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">CFO</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul><br>

              <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"
   data-toggle="modal"
   data-target="#portfolioModal2">About Pody</a>
                    </div>
                </div>


 <!-- Modal Views -->
<div class="modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Dan founded the company in 1970 as a small lawncare company which quickly grew into the industry leading design build firm it is today. Dan has extensive project management experience serving as the general contractor on a plethora of different types of engagements for over four decades. As a testament to Dan's success the Ohio Nursery & Landscape Association Awards Program has accredited him with 26 state awards and the Civic Garden Center of Greater Cincinnati has accredited him with 20 Civic Beautification Awards. Dan is also a certified pesticide applicator.</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="modal fade" id="portfolioModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Pody became involved in the business in 1980.  Pody manages the accounting and financial analysis for the businesses. Pody spent three years of her collegiate career at the Ohio State University before completing her Bachelor's in Business Administration from the University of Cincinnati with an emphasis in marketing. </h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best to extend Bootstrap modal with Bootbox, here is link to plugin

http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

And call it like this

```
bootbox.dialog({
                title: "This is a form in a modal.",
                message: '<div class="row">  ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-12"> ' +
                    '<form class="form-horizontal"> ' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4"> ' +
                    '<input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" class="form-control input-md"> ' +
                    '<span class="help-block">Here goes your name</span> </div> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '<div class="form-group"> ' +
                    '<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="awesomeness">How awesome is this?</label> ' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4"> <div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-0"> ' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-0" value="Really awesome" checked="checked"> ' +
                    'Really awesome </label> ' +
                    '</div><div class="radio"> <label for="awesomeness-1"> ' +
                    '<input type="radio" name="awesomeness" id="awesomeness-1" value="Super awesome"> Super awesome </label> ' +
                    '</div> ' +
                    '</div> </div>' +
                    '</form> </div>  </div>',
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        label: "Save",
                        className: "btn-success",
                        callback: function () {
                            var name = $('#name').val();
                            var answer = $("input[name='awesomeness']:checked").val());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: ok, I did see a reference to bootbox before...I will check it out. Thanks